# What's Return & what am I doing wrong(Lua)

Tags: lua

I have two questions, one being what is return in lua? I have been searching all over the internet looking for what it does/means and its purpouse. 2. I am having trouble coding this section:

```
testGrade={}
testGrade.Joe = 86
testGrade.Josh = 75
testGrade.Jack = 12
testGrade.Andrew = 0
testGrade.Larry = 100
testGrade.Noah = 94
testGrade.Blakely = 67

for k,v in pairs(testGrade) do
    local maxGrade = 100
    if testGrade[grade] == 100 then
        Msg("Congratulations "..k..", you scored a "..v.." out of "..maxGrade.." getting every question right!\n");
    elseif testGrade[grade] >= 90 then
        Msg("Congratulations "..k..", you scored a "..v.." out of "..maxGrade.." getting an A!\n");
    elseif testGrade[grade] >= 80 then
        Msg(k..", you scored a "..v.." out of "..maxGrade.." getting a B.\n");
    elseif testGrade[grade] >= 70 then
        Msg(k..", you scored a "..v.." out of "..maxGrade.." getting a C, try harder next time.\n");
    elseif testGrade[grade] >= 60 then
        Msg(k..", you scored a "..v.." out of "..maxGrade.." getting a D, you need to study!\n");
    elseif testGrade[grade] == 0 then
        Msg(k..", you scored a "..v.." out of "..maxGrade.." getting NOTHING right! Did you even try?!\n"); 
    else
        Msg(k..", you scored a "..v.." out of "..maxGrade.." making you fail. You need to try harder and study!\n"); 
    end
end
```

I was trying to do some practice coding, but I got stumped on this. Commenting is very helpful ;)

Comment: It returns a value from a function. From [2.4.4 Control Structures](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.4.4): "The return statement is used to return values from a function or a chunk (which is just a function). Functions and chunks can return more than one valueThe return statement is used to return values from a function or a chunk (which is just a function). Functions and chunks can return more than one value, ...".

Comment: Seems like you want to replace every case of `testGrade[grade]` with just `v`.  You use `k` and `v` in other places so I'm not sure where the disconnect is.

Comment: @Retired Ninja Ah, sorry. I forgot to change that part. I was using a previous older outdated code I used and I used grade as a variable before I learned other tactics of looping. Really tired atm and didn't spot that. I was so confused lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`return` returns a value from a function.

From [2.4.4 Control Structures](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.4.4):

> The return statement is used to return values from a function or a chunk (which is just a function). Functions and chunks can return more than one valueThe return statement is used to return values from a function or a chunk (which is just a function). Functions and chunks can return more than one value, and so the syntax for the return statement is
>
> stat ::= return [explist]

You don't have a function here so you don't need `return` anywhere.

You are attempting to use `testGrade[grade]` to get the grade of the current student but `grade` has no value (you never assign it anywhere).

The value of `k` in the loop is the key in the table (the student's name).

The value of `v` in the loop is the value for the key in the table (the student's grade).

So change `for k,v in pairs(testGrade) do` to `for student, grade in pairs(testGrade) do` and replace all `testGrade[grade]` in the comparisons with just `grade` and it should work and replace all uses of `k` with `student` and `v` with `grade` and it will work.

A more minimal change would be to (as RetiredNinja just added in a comment) replace `testGrade[grade]` with `v` in the comparisons.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I forgot to change that part. I was using a previous older outdated code I used and I used grade as a variable before I learned other tactics of looping. Thanks!